# How to correct error in Bitbucket Pipeline running md-to-pdf

Tags: puppeteer, bitbucket-pipelines

I am getting the below error when trying to run md-to-pdf (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-to-pdf) in a Bitbucket Pipeline script (see script below).

**Error**

```
ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. 
See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

**bitbucket-pipelines.yaml file**

```
image: buildkite/puppeteer:v1.15.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install -g md-to-pdf
          - doc="appendix"
          - md-to-pdf --config-file config.json ${doc}.md
```

**config.json file**

I tried to follow instructions for this. Is this config.json malformed?

```
{
  "launch_options": {
    "args": ["no-sandbox"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
{
  "launch_options": {
    "args": ["--no-sandbox"]
  }
}
```

Comment: For cli: ```md-to-pdf --launch-options='{"headless":"new","args":["--no-sandbox"]}'```